# Why does Chrome and Firefox crash while uploading a file larger than 30 MB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file on the server in my angularjs app. The file is upload in base64 string format. The things work fine when the file size is less than 30 MB but the browsers (both chrome and firefox) crash when he file size is more than 30 MB. The browsers crash before the post request is made.

Here is the code of my controller for uploading the file:

```
$scope.addMyFile = function(t,pid,id,week,day) {
    $("#upload"+t+pid+id).each(function() {
           var $input = $(this);
           var inputFiles = this.files;
               if(inputFiles == undefined || inputFiles.length == 0) return;
           var inputFile = inputFiles[0];
           var inputFileSize = inputFile.size;

           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function(event) {
               var dataString = event.target.result;

               var firstPart =  dataString.split(',')[0];
               var secondPart = dataString.split(',')[1];

               dataString = secondPart;

               var fileName = inputFile.name;

               var fileExtension = firstPart.split('/')[1].split(';')[0];

               reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
       });
};
```

UploadMyFile Function:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(type,week,day,fileName,fileExtension,dataString) {
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.uploadBar = true;

var fileUploadUrl = serverURL;

var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: fileUploadUrl, 
        headers: { 'Accept' :'application/json','Content-Type' :'application/json', authToken:userauthToken, 'Accept-Language': 'en'},
        data: { name : fileName, documentString:dataString, extension: fileExtension}
     });

     request.success(
       function(data) {
           $scope.uploadStatus = data.status;
           $scope.getWeekList(type);
           $scope.uploadBar = false;
           alert('The file has been successfully uploaded.');
     });
     $scope.loading = false;
     request.error(
        function(data, status) {
            console.log(status);
            $scope.uploadStatus = data.status || "Request failed";
            alert('The file could not be uploaded. Please try again.');
     });
};
```

Comment: I'd venture that a 30MB string is going to be a challenge on most platforms. Why not send your data up as binary? What's with the base64 string?

Comment: Apart of what @spender said - I believe you have a typo in your code. You didn't close the `reader.onload` curly bracket (`}`). Additionaly, `reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);` should be _outside_ of the `onload` event handler.

Comment: @spender, I have to send the file as base64 string as the server side code is written in that way. As of now, it would be very difficult for me to change that. Is there any work around for the base64 method?

Also, I did some R & D and found that the browser crashes when the file is converted into base64 string.

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk, I am sorry for the typo but I have correctly written my code. Did some error here while hiding some crucial info.